# Terraform script error while deploying app service CDN endpoint

Tags: azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure, azure-cdn

Getting the following error while deploying.

```
Error: Error waiting for CDN Endpoint "website-dev-appservice" (Profile "website-dev-eastus2-cdn" / Resource Group "website-dev-eastus2-rg") to finish creating: Code="BadRequest" 

Message="{\"ErrorMessage\":\"Errors found in Model: OriginHostHeader must match the regex '(^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_\\\\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\\\\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\\\\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$)|((?:[:0-9A-Fa-f]+))'.\"}"
```

what could be the issue here?

Comment: when ask for help, it could be useful if you show your code

Answer (score 4):

Even though hashicorp doc says origin_host_header is an optional field but here Scripts needs origin_host_header to be specified which default value is the domain e.g origin_host_header = www.google.com
Just add origin_host_header, It should work.